# T-SQL: Partitioning on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I am having a problem partitioning with the following SQL statement:

```
Declare @Total int;
Declare @MaxBlockSize int = 3;
Declare @testGrpPct float = .25;

DECLARE @students TABLE(
    id bigint NOT NULL
    ,TimeZone nvarchar(50)
)

Insert  into @students (id, TimeZone)
values  (154058701677130000,'Central Standard Time')
        ,(157089441549513000,'Central Standard Time')
        ,(152873971640300000,'Central Standard Time')
        ,(153611923609744000,'Mountain Standard Time')
        ,(157091006083626000,'Mountain Standard Time')
        ,(157087925333783000,'Mountain Standard Time')
        ,(153610132054733000,'Central Standard Time')
        ,(154060631031804000,'Central Standard Time')
        ,(157088513769468000,'Central Standard Time')
        ,(153615959083840000,'Central Standard Time')
        ,(152813428061631000,'Central Standard Time')
        ,(156948713062134000,'Central Standard Time')
        ,(153609396063433000,'Central Standard Time')
        ,(157092455047885000,'Central Standard Time')
        ,(153505362979714000,'Central Standard Time')
        ,(152814176216413000,'Central Standard Time')
        ,(157094637059044000,'Mountain Standard Time')
        ,(157089221575046000,'Mountain Standard Time')
        ,(152806972331521000,'Mountain Standard Time')
        ,(157087495031747000,'Mountain Standard Time')
        ,(157092954337834000,'Mountain Standard Time')
        ,(157094331126510000,'Mountain Standard Time')
        ,(152873684187870000,'Mountain Standard Time')
        ,(157090267743515000,'Mountain Standard Time')
        ,(157093842020332000,'Mountain Standard Time')
        ,(157088933174703000,'Mountain Standard Time')

Set @Total = (
    Select  Count(*)
    FROM    @students
)

Select  WinningGroup
        ,CEILING(((ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by WinningGroup order by WinningGroup, timezone))-1)/@MaxBlockSize) BlockNbr
        ,id
        ,TimeZone
from    (
            --Determines who is in test vs winning groups
            SELECT  case when (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Newid())) <= @testGrpPct * @Total then 0 else 1 end as WinningGroup
                    ,id
                    ,TimeZone
            FROM    @students
        ) A
ORDER   by WinningGroup
        ,CEILING(((ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by WinningGroup order by WinningGroup, timezone))-1)/@MaxBlockSize)
```

Desired results should look something like this:

| WinningGroup | BlockNbr | id | TimeZone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 152813428061631000 | Central Standard Time |
| 0 | 0 | 152813428061631000 | Central Standard Time |
| 0 | 0 | 153610132054733000 | Central Standard Time |
| 0 | 1 | 157087925333783000 | Mountain Standard Time |
| 0 | 1 | 157094331126510000 | Mountain Standard Time |
| 0 | 1 | 157094637059044000 | Mountain Standard Time |
| 0 | 2 | 152873684187870000 | Mountain Standard Time |
| 1 | 0 | 156948713062134000 | Central Standard Time |
| 1 | 0 | 154058701677130000 | Central Standard Time |
| 1 | 0 | 152814176216413000 | Central Standard Time |
| 1 | 1 | 154060631031804000 | Central Standard Time |
| 1 | 1 | 153609396063433000 | Central Standard Time |
| 1 | 1 | 157088513769468000 | Central Standard Time |
| 1 | 2 | 157092455047885000 | Central Standard Time |
| 1 | 2 | 152873971640300000 | Central Standard Time |
| 1 | 2 | 153505362979714000 | Central Standard Time |
| 1 | 3 | 153615959083840000 | Central Standard Time |
| 1 | 3 | 157089441549513000 | Central Standard Time |
| 1 | 4 | 157090267743515000 | Mountain Standard Time |
| 1 | 4 | 157092954337834000 | Mountain Standard Time |
| 1 | 4 | 153611923609744000 | Mountain Standard Time |
| 1 | 5 | 157091006083626000 | Mountain Standard Time |
| 1 | 5 | 157089221575046000 | Mountain Standard Time |
| 1 | 5 | 157087495031747000 | Mountain Standard Time |
| 1 | 6 | 157093842020332000 | Mountain Standard Time |
| 1 | 6 | 157088933174703000 | Mountain Standard Time |
| 1 | 6 | 152806972331521000 | Mountain Standard Time |

The goal is the assign a `blockNbr` based on the `wgroup` and `timezone`. Each block can have a max of 3 students (using ceiling and MaxBlockSize for that). However, each block may only contain a single time zone and a single wgroup. If you reference the table above, you'll see that WinningGroup 1, BlockNbr 3 only has 2 records before the next record is in a different time zone so that person gets put into a different block so each block only contains 1 time zone.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Have you tried NTILE(@MaxBlockSize) OVER(PARTITION BY wgroup, timezone ORDER BY wgroup, timezone)

Comment: Sample data and desired results is always useful for SQL query questions.

Comment: your code looks like it will return a rowid based on the partition of wgroup,timezone.  you need to add member and then filter where occurrences of rowid are less than equal to 3.  Define what a block number is?

Comment: NTILE(@MaxBlockSize) will return all records in a max of 3 blocks, not 3 records per block. Either way, I still appreciate the suggestion!

Comment: From what I make of your requirements and your sample output you need to add `timezone` to ``PARTITION BY` i.e. `ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by WinningGroup, timezone order by WinningGroup, timezone)`

Answer (score 0):

try group by before order by

```
    Select  WinningGroup
        ,CEILING(((ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by WinningGroup,WinningGroup, timezone order by WinningGroup, timezone))-1)/@MaxBlockSize) BlockNbr
        ,TimeZone
from    (
            --Determines who is in test vs winning groups
            SELECT  case when (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Newid())) <= @testGrpPct * @Total then 0 else 1 end as WinningGroup
                    ,TimeZone
            FROM    @students
        ) A
  GROUP BY  WinningGroup,WinningGroup, timezone
ORDER   by WinningGroup
        ,CEILING(((ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by WinningGroup,WinningGroup, timezone order by WinningGroup, timezone))-1)/@MaxBlockSize)
```